# Threading windows mobile 6 compact framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm trying to figure out how threading works on a windows mobile device (6.0) with compact framework 2.0. For now I'm trying to make a progress bar, since it is one of the most basic things and basically in every tutorial I found.

From normal windows forms - apps I'm used to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myProgressBar.BeginInvoke(
    new Action(() =>
        {
            myProgressBar.Value = i;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    ));
}
```

But I get an error at `new Action(()...`:

> The usage of type "`System.Action<T>`"(generic) requires the 1-Type argument
>   (translated from German)

It seems `Action()` is not available to me, only `Action<T>()`. But I don't know what parameter `T` should be or what argument to give to `Action<T>()`.

Comment: By the way, consider using .NET CF 3.5 instead of 2.0

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you code can perform not exactly you are waiting from it, as you are using the closures here on `i` variable, for correct work you should copy `i` to the local variable. Also, you can simplify your code, and not to create an `Action` object, but [use simple lambda expression here, and convert it to `Action`](https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/control-invoke-and-begininvoke-using-lamba-and-anonymous-delegates/).

So your final code could be like this (added some small corrections for the increment and `var` keyword):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var localI = i;
    myProgressBar.BeginInvoke(
      (Action)(() =>
        {
            myProgressBar.Value = localI;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
      ));
}
```

As the non-generic class isn't available for you, you can cast the method you are passing to the `BeginInvoke` to the some delegate from standart library, for example, [`MethodInvoker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) (supported in .NET Framework Client Profile
), and use not lambda, but `delegate` keyword for a code simplicity:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var localI = i;
    myProgressBar.BeginInvoke(
      (MethodInvoker) delegate ()
        {
            myProgressBar.Value = localI;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
      );
}
```

**But I want you to be aware that `Thread.Sleep` here will freeze the UI thread, not the background one, as you are invoking the `Action` on target's thread.** So you've better to put that code out of UI update:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var localI = i;
    myProgressBar.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate ()
        {
            myProgressBar.Value = localI;
        });
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The main problem is still there though. `(Action)` won't compile since `Action()` is not availabel. The only thing available is `Action<T>()`. So I have to specify a type and giva a variable of that type.

Comment: Did you try that? You don't need to create action with constructor, only casting is needed).

Comment: @FNR What is the signature for `BeginInvoke` exactly? Can it be found on MSDN?

Comment: I tried. I still get the same error message (see original question). The signature is `BeginInvike(Delegate)`. For Delegate I'm using `Action()`. But in this framework there is no constructor for Action, only `Action<T>()`. So I'd need something like `Action<string>(("myString") => ...)`.

Comment: @FNR Updated the answer. I still want to notify about your `Sleep` method - it will freeze UI thread, move it out of UI-updating logic!

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But it seems `MethodInvoker` isn't implemented in the Compact Framework. I finally found a way to get it to run though. I'll post an answer with the solution. And thanks for pointing out the `Sleep` problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87271/discussion-between-fnr-and-vmatm).

Answer (score 1):

When looking for an alternative for `MethodInvoker`as pointed out by @VMAtm I finally found a way that works with the compact framework:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var localI = i;
    myProgressBar.BeginInvoke(
    (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
            myProgressBar.Value = localI;
        }
    );
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```